# EF7: deleted data from relationship table on context.SaveChanges()

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, entity-framework-core

Forgive me for not knowing how to technically express the situation...

Main table, drop down table. Saving an Updated entity for main table (which holds FK for drop down table, deletes value for that record in the drop down table.

Why would changing a value in the main table, *delete* the value for the corresponding record in the drop down table?

**save function**

```
    public void UpdateApplicationDetails(Application UpdatedApp)
    {
        AtlasContext updatecontext = new AtlasContext();
        Application currAppRecord = _context.Apps.Where(a => a.Id == UpdatedApp.Id).Single();

        currAppRecord = UpdatedApp;

        updatecontext.Apps.Update(UpdatedApp);
        updatecontext.SaveChanges();
    }
```

Will update with necessary info if requested. Thanks for taking the time

Comment: Are you sure that the `UpdatedApp` object has the proper FK set. If thats null, then that relation will not be available after update. Update- I read the question wrong...This should not delete the entry from the child table! Check the entity state of the foreign key object before the save changes.

Comment: So, turns out EF7 is working exactly as expected, just not the way I thought it would. This is the solution I'm in the middle of implementing...

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/efcore-and-ef6/porting/port-edmx